# Reflexive pronoun

Tags: personal-pronouns, reflexives, grammatical-gender, pronominal-agreement

What reflexive pronoun should I use when referring to a city, *itself* or *herself*?

Lisbon is a city that does not show herself/itself.

Comment: Historically, cities, ships, the ocean, etc, were treated as feminine for the purposes of pronouns. That practice has fallen into disuse, however, and the neuter *itself* would be strongly favored today (except perhaps in language which specifically aims to imitate the florid usage of the past, possibly for rhetorical purposes).

Comment: (Incidentally, this is why in classical art,  *Liberty*, *Brittania*, and other such abstract notions were rendered as women in sculpture, painting and even coins and bills.)

Comment: @DanBron Good point but,lest there be any doubt about liberty's femininity,  it really calls for Eugène Delacroix's [*La Liberté guidant le peuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eug%C3%A8ne_Delacroix_-_La_libert%C3%A9_guidant_le_peuple.jpg)

Comment: It depends on the style you're going for. If you use _herself_ to refer to a city in casual everyday speech, it will sound archaic and affected.

Answer (score 2):

In ordinary speech, always *itself*. But there is a long poetic tradition of referring to cities as *she*, so in elegant writing, *herself* will be fine.